# how to pass to an activity with timer and cancel the timer with a skip button

Tags: android, android-activity, timer, skip

i just want to know how to do this... this is my code and i don't find a way to do what i want...

```
public class IntroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int TIME_OUT = 5000; //Time to launch the another activity
TimerTask mTimerTask;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);


    mTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, login.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }, TIME_OUT);
        }};
}

public void skip(View view) {
    Intent entrar = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, login.class);
    startActivity(entrar);
    finish();
    stopTask();

}
public void stopTask() {
    mTimerTask.cancel();
}

}
```

i want to go to the next activity when the time is over, and stop the timer and go to the next activity when i push the skip button.

this code doesn't stop the timer, but skip and stop already on the skip method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TimerTask with Timer class, and note: if you run a one time execution with TimerTask, and the task is scheduled, so whatever you called cancel method, it will execute complete.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(mTimerTask, 5000);
....
mTimerTask = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        if(YourActivity.this.isDestroyed()){
            return;
        }else {
            ..... // your code here
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: it makes my app stop